# Why MySQL query is not compiling in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have a problem with call SQL query under Oracle 11g. Under MySQL works fine.

Just look at [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c94/1):

```
(SELECT IF(c.name IS NULL, '- Unknow -', c.name) as name,
    v.site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
    0  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name, v.site)
union(
SELECT IF(c.name IS NULL, '- Unknow -', c.name) as name,
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name)
UNION (
SELECT '- All -',
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
    1  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country)
ORDER BY name, isAll DESC, site
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem with this code?

Comment: You need quotation marks (") instead of apostrophes (').

Comment: After change from " to ' there is no difference. You can see it sql fiddle under link in my post (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c94/24)

Comment: Yes, I see. Also my comment was only for column names and not character strings.

Comment: When I ran individual queries, I had the 1st one run normally and second is producing an error.

Comment: Oracle has no `IF` which you can tell right away when reading the SQL reference manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things wrong...

Firstly, `IF()` isn't valid syntax in Oracle. You need to change it to a `CASE` statement.

Secondly, You can't name a column using ''. So you need to strip away the '' from 'isAll'.

Finally, you're ordering by site but you haven't actually named the column.

The final query should look something like this:

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN c.name IS NULL THEN '- Unknow -' ELSE c.name END as name,
    v.site as site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
    0  isAll
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name, v.site)
UNION (
SELECT CASE WHEN c.name IS NULL THEN '- Unknow -' ELSE c.name END as name,
    '- All -' as site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  isAll
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name )
UNION (
SELECT '- All -',
    '- All -' as site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  isAll
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country)
ORDER BY name, isAll DESC, site
```

You can test in this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c94/55

Answer (score 1):

Further to Grant's answer, a couple of other optimisations.

You might like to replace:

```
 CASE WHEN c.name IS NULL THEN '- Unknow -' ELSE c.name END
```

with:

```
 Coalesce(c.name,'- Unknow -')
```

Also, you are aggregating at multiple levels, and there's a syntax for that which will be much more efficient and less wordy: GROUP BY ROLLUP()

Tim Hall has a very good write-up on advanced group-by topics here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php

If you decide not to use ROLLUP then change the UNIONs into UNION ALL -- UNION has an implicit distinct which would do nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updates [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c94/77) that runs.  Please make sure that it still produces the result you're expecting.